# Can you add a css class or id to Rails <%= @time.now %>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't want to wrap the ruby code in anything? I have several variables in my code and I want to give each a class. I understand how to do this with a form tag, but not this. Does anyone have an answer or solution?

Thanks

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b3693bf2f827789a8b1ef5e0a3f653ed58089b1e/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L45), isn't that `Time.now` going to just give you something like a string?  It would seem to me that you'd end up having to wrap it in actual HTML tags (or JavaScript, etc.) in order to add a class or an id.  Do you have an example of what the HTML output looks like when you use `<%= @time.now %>`?

Comment: I guess I was too specific with <%= @time.now %>. More importantly, I also have a case where I have <%= twitter_helper_link(@user.twitter_handle) %> and I want to create a large border around it, so that mobile users can click a "large button" instead of the text. If I create a class, I can increase padding around it and create a button. I just need to make it a class.

Answer (score 2):

Like summea said, Time.now will just give you a string. To add a class you could put it inside a `div`, `span` or `time` HTML tag:

```
<%= content_tag :div, @time.now, class: 'your-css-class' %>
<%= content_tag :span, @time.now, class: 'your-css-class' %>
<%= time_tag @time.now, class: 'your-css-class' %>
```

These would give you:

```
<div class="your-css-class">TIME_VALUE</div>
<span class="your-css-class">TIME_VALUE</span>
<time datetime="TIME_VALUE" class="your-css-class">TIME_VALUE</time>
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_tag for info on the `time_tag`

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to up vote and mark as correct if you're happy with the answer ;)

Comment: Tried it a few different ways, but just creates 2 different anchors. One for the string and one for the a/div/span. I want to create a padded anchor for the variable. Something easy for iphone users to tap